# GtkWidget call back (toggled button) does not pass the data

Tags: callback, widget, gtk

I have the following code:

```
int DT=45;
g_print("--Set: %d\n",DT);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "toggled", G_CALLBACK(cave_dive_toggle_cb), (gpointer) &DT);
```

and the callback function:

```
void cave_dive_toggle_cb(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    int *ID=(int *)data;
    int DT= *ID;
    if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget)))
     g_print("clicked %d\n",DT);
    else
     g_print("unclicked %d\n",DT);
}
```

When opening the dialog and clicking the button, I always see:

```
--Set: 45 
clicked 0 
unclicked 0 
clicked 0 
unclicked 0 
clicked 0 
unclicked 0
```

Am I doing something wrong? As far as I understand the Gtk documentation, I am not. I tried also swapped version and took the first parameter to be sure that I wrote correct CB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `DT` is a local variable so once the function exits it doesn't exist anymore. What you need to do is use the GINT_TO_POINTER and GPOINTER_TO_INT macros like so:

```
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "toggled", G_CALLBACK (cave_dive_toggle_cb), GINT_TO_POINTER (DT));
```

and

```
void cave_dive_toggle_cb (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    int DT = GPOINTER_TO_INT (data);

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that the DT exist till the dialog is open. Maybe I will read something about GTK ;) Thanks!

Comment: Cool. If it worked for you, click the up arrow and accept the answer